# How can I achieve Something Like this?

Tags: ios, swift3, label, edit

[image]

Label Rotation and Scaling is already done I have Used `CGAffineTransform` for Rotation and Scaling but I want That white colour's Icon on Label's Border. How can I add This on Label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using StoryBoard or XIB then you can achieve it by add `UILabel` And that white button in side `UIView`.
If you are doing it by programmatically then you can directly add that white button as `subView` of `UILabel`

Below useful 3rd party library

- https://github.com/zedoul/ZDStickerView
- https://github.com/Thavasidurai/TDResizerView